# How to change text color of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton

I am writing a simple minesweeper game and it works now, but I am working on the pretty details like making each number a different color.

I keep running into errors when I try to set the text color on the `JButton`. I can change the text easily enough and the background, but not the text color specifically.

The part that keeps getting all mucked up is:

```
total = Integer.toString(count);
jb.setText(total);              
if(count == 1)
    jb.setTextColor(Color.blue);
if(count == 2)
    jb.setTextColor(Color.green);
if(count == 3)
    jb.setTextColor(Color.red);
```

For some reason my error is:

```
MS.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
                    jb.setTextColor(Color.blue);
                      ^
  symbol:   method setTextColor(Color)
  location: variable jb of type JButton
MS.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                    jb.setTextColor(Color.green);
                      ^
  symbol:   method setTextColor(Color)
  location: variable jb of type JButton
MS.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
                    jb.setTextColor(Color.red);
                      ^
  symbol:   method setTextColor(Color)
  location: variable jb of type JButton
3 errors
Process javac exited with code 1
```

This occurs whenever I try to compile, but when I change it to say `setBackgroundColor` instead of `setTextColor` it works just fine.

Comment: I think you want `setForegroundColor()`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I tried putting that in, but it still gives me the same error(I am just replacing setTextColor with setForegroundColor or is that the wrong thing to do?)

Comment: sorry, that's supposed to be `SetForeground()` Check out the [documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SetFontandforegroundcolorforaJLabel.htm)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`setTextColor` is undefined for JButton. To set the `JButton` text color, you can use `setForeground`.

```
button.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

Comment: can you put that into code? When i do it i still get the same error but here is how I am using it: jb.setForegroundColor(Color.red);