# Losing Font when HTML Tags are Used with JButton/JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts

I am having issues with the following code block:

```
    JButton button1 = new JButton("");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("");
    try {
        arabicContentFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, (new File(".\\Arabic_font.ttf"))).deriveFont(50f);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error opening font file!");
    }

    button1.setText("عَلَّمَ");
    button2.setText(String.format("<html><font color='red'>%s</font></html>", "عَلَّمَ"));
    button1.setFont(arabicContentFont);
    button2.setFont(arabicContentFont);
```

When my application runs, it displays button1 correctly, but when I add the HTML tags, because I want to format the color of individual letters, I lose my applied font on button2.

Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: AFAIR `setFont` fails once we are rendering HTML.  The font of the HTML takes precedence.  I also suspect the font needs to be registered with the JRE in order to use it for HTML.  See also [Setting custom font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717481/setting-custom-font) & [Getting fonts, sizes, bold,…etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc),

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I installed the font on my PC and all is well.

Comment: *"I installed the font on my PC"* How's that supposed to work for anyone who ***isn't*** you?  I would not go asking users to install a font to use my applications.  The linked questions showed how to do this **without** installing the font.

Comment: HTML markup just to [set the color](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15393426/17300)? `button2.setForeground(Color.RED);`