# How to change color of text in a button

Tags: java, javafx

How do you change the color of a text inside a button node?

I tried this:

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white");
```

But it only added color to the button.

Comment: can you try `btn.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: @YCF_L How do I use setTextFill when I want a specific hex code for the color?

Comment: Can you try this please `btn.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));`

Comment: There are many questions and answers on stackoverflow.com 
Before, asking a question you need to do some research to check if you question is already there.
Please, read the guidelines before I participating.

Comment: @MohammedFadhl if it is a duplicate, then vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text color of a JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393385/how-to-change-text-color-of-a-jbutton)

Comment: @MohammedFadhl that answer is for java swing, not javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaFX there are various ways to set the color of a button's text:

From hex:

```
private static Button createButton() {
    final Button button = new Button("red");
    button.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    return button;
}
```

With predefined colors:

```
private static Button createButton() {
    final Button button = new Button("red");
    button.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    return button;
}
```

From RGB values:

```
private static Button createButton() {
    final Button button = new Button("red");
    button.setTextFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    return button;
}
```

From HSB values:

```
private static Button createButton() {
    final Button button = new Button("red");
    button.setTextFill(Color.hsb(0, 1, 1));
    return button;
}
```

From color where RGB is within a range of 0.0-1.0

```
private static Button createButton() {
    final Button button = new Button("red");
    button.setTextFill(Color.color(1, 0, 0));
    return button;
}
```

Pick whichever suits your needs